# What written language is more commonly used for video games in China?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, classical-chinese

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the relative literacy rates in for simplified and traditional characters?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/what-are-the-relative-literacy-rates-in-for-simplified-and-traditional-character)

Just wondering what language to use in game menus, buttons, and settings.

Comment: It depends on where the video games are sold. Even if the titles in games are in English, the publisher would use British English in the UK and American English in the USA.

Comment: @Huang Even games sold in the USA may occasionally use British English if going for a more traditional or European style, but the key is still using whatever language the users will still understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably you'd better prepare 2 versions of translation for the game menus/buttons to better sell your game.

However, either Simplified Chinese or Traditional Chinese is OK, since most of the case you could use a locale converter such as AppLocale under windows to convert different encodes. But if the game cannot use such tools, better prepare 2 versions.

As for the Classical Chinese, it depends on your game type, if it's an RPG, maybe some of the poem/idiom can be translated to Classical Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about China only, then it is Simplified Chinese(SC).

All of main-land China us SC, except Hong Kong, which use Traditional Chinese(TC).

Taiwan (if you consider it part of China now) also use TC.

2011 Population ([Worldbank.org](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?cid=GPD_1)):

```
China 1344M
HK       7M
Taiwan  23M
```

Comment: What about Singapore and Malaysia?

Comment: Singapore used to use TC exclusively for Chinese writing, but they change it to SC in recent years (within the last 10yrs). So it is a mix now. Malaysia is similar situation, TC/SC mix, but more and more towards SC, as China influence is getting stronger in recent years.